# How do I get the most recent file based on a date in the filename?

Tags: java, file, date, for-loop, stream

I have a directory which contains files like this :
{users_20221104.txt | users_20221105.txt |
users_20221106.txt

dealers_20221104.txt |
dealers_20221105.txt |
dealers_20221106.txt |

nations_20221104.txt |
nations_20221105.txt |
nations_20221106.txt }

I need to retrieve only the last file of each occurence, which means users_20221106, dealers_20221106 and nations_20221106

At the moment I have something like this :

```
    private void downloadFiles()  {
        List<String> filesPath = ftpClient.listFiles(ftpFolderIn);
        String usersFileTxt = null;
        String dealerFileTxt = null;
        String nationFileTxt = null;
        
        for (String filepath : filesPath) {
            if (filepath.contains("users")) {
                usersFileTxt = filepath;
            }
            if (filepath.contains("dealers")) {
                dealerFileTxt = filepath;
            }
            if (filepath.contains("nations")) {
                nationFileTxt = filepath;
            }
        }
        usersFile = ftpClient.downloadFile(usersFileTxt);
        dealerFile = ftpClient.downloadFile(dealerFileTxt);
        nationFile = ftpClient.downloadFile(nationFileTxt);
    }
```

Comment: *At the moment I have something that is working but I have to add the "time" treatment in order to get the last file of each* - You are not processing the names on the basis of date at all. All you are doing is picking up the last file of the respective prefix. So, it doesn't matter if filenames contain the time in the end.

Comment: What I wanted to say is that i'm missing the processing of the date, I edited my post I just realized that it was not clear

Answer (score 2):

Loop through your file names.

Extract the date portion. One way to do this is to use methods on `String` class such as `split` and `replace`.

Parse the date portion as a `LocalDate`. Use the predefined formatter for parsing the “basic” (condensed) version of the standard ISO 8601 format.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE ) ;
```

Compare the dates using their natural ordering, with `isBefore`, `isAfter`, and `isEqual`. Remember which file has the latest date as you loop.

Answer (score 2):

A clean approach would be to create a `Compartor` and use the same with the stream by initializing it with corresponding prefixes.

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

class FilesComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    private String prefix;

    FilesComparator(String prefix) {
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("'" + prefix + "'uuuuMMdd'.txt'");
        LocalDate ldt1 = LocalDate.parse(s1, parser);
        LocalDate ldt2 = LocalDate.parse(s2, parser);
        return ldt1.compareTo(ldt2);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> files = List.of(
                "users_20221104.txt", "users_20221106.txt", "users_20221105.txt",
                "dealers_20221104.txt", "dealers_20221106.txt", "dealers_20221105.txt",
                "nations_20221104.txt", "nations_20221106.txt", "nations_20221105.txt");

        String usersFileTxt = getLatestFile(files, "users_").get();
        System.out.println(usersFileTxt);

        String dealersFileTxt = getLatestFile(files, "dealers_").get();
        System.out.println(dealersFileTxt);

        String nationsFileTxt = getLatestFile(files, "nations_").get();
        System.out.println(nationsFileTxt);
    }

    static Optional<String> getLatestFile(List<String> files, String prefix) {
        return files.stream()
                .filter(filename -> filename.startsWith(prefix))
                .max(new FilesComparator(prefix));
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
users_20221106.txt
dealers_20221106.txt
nations_20221106.txt
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**